# Create chart in another spreadsheet file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my code

```
var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("-idspreadsheet file-");
var hojaExterna = ss2.getSheetByName(celdaIndicador);

        /**Validacion Tiempo */
        if (celdaTiempo == ("Semestral")) {
          var rangoA = hojaExterna.getRange("I44:K49").getValues();
          var rangoB = hojaExterna.getRange("D44:F49").getValues();
          var datos = ss1.getSheetByName("Datos");
          datos.getRange(1, 1).setValue(rangoA);
          datos.getRange(1, 4).setValue(rangoB);
          Logger.log(rangoA);
          Logger.log(rangoB);

          var grafico = datos.newChart()
            .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.GAUGE)
            .addRange(hojaExterna.getRange("I44:K49"))
            .setOption('backgroundColor', '#B3EAF0')
            .setOption('redFrom', 0)
            .setOption('redTo', 50)
            .setOption('yellowFrom', 50)
            .setOption('yellowTo', 70)
            .setOption('greenFrom', 70)
            .setOption('greenTo', 100)
            .setOption('minorTicks', 5)
            .setPosition(6, 6, 0, 0)
            .build();
          datos.insertChart(grafico);
        }
```

I can't send or export it to another spreadsheet file. Always show me

> Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id -idspreadsheet file-

Comment: In your showing script, it seems that `celdaTiempo` and `ss1` are not declared. And, where the error of `Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id -idspreadsheet file-` occur in your showing script?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The script is uncomplete and there are important details that are missing, i.e. assuming that `-idspreadsheet file-` is a spreadsheet id and not literally `-idspreadsheet file-`, how do you got the spreadsheet id. Please add a [mcve] (maybe anything after `var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("-idspreadsheet file-");` is not required to reproduce the error)

Answer (score 0):

"-idspreadsheet file-" in your SpreadsheetApp.openById() is not a spreadsheet Id it is simply a string.  You need to get the id of your spreadsheet.  To do that in Gooble Drive right click on your spreadsheet and "Get Link".  Press "Copy Link".  Go to the Script editor and paste the link intothe openById command.  You will see something like this.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234/edit?usp=sharing

The spreadsheet id is the 44 characters "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234"